# CSS div inline-block + img max-width

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've been looking for answer for some time now & was tinkering with it for a while but cannot seem to find solution.
Probably it's easy as hell but I cannot wrap my head around it.

I'v got image with inline style of 'max-width:44%' wrapped in  container.

How do I make container to be the same width as image inside it?

```
<div class="post" >
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" style="vertical-align:bottom; max-width:44%;"/>                                        
</div>

.post{position:relative; display:inline-block;  border: 1px solid lime; }
```

Here's jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/37Fyb/2/

Answer (score 1):

A percentage width sets the child element to that percentage of the width of its parent. In this case, the child is your `img` and the parent is your `.post` divider. Setting the image's  width to 44% sets it to 44% of the divider's width - meaning no matter what you to the container, the image will always be 44% of its width.

One way to get around this problem would be to give your `img` 100% width and your `.post` divider the 44% width, then wrap that in another divider with fixed width:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="post" >
        <img src="..." style="... width:100%;" />                                        
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outerContainer {
    width:202px;
}
.post{
    border: 1px solid lime;
    width:44%;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/37Fyb/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.post{
  position:relative; 
  display:inline-block;  
  border: 1px solid lime; 
  max-width:44%}

img{ 
  vertical-align:bottom; 
  max-width:100%;
}
```